# Set default value as numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, default-value

I have a class MyClass which stores an integer `a`. I want to define a function inside it that takes a numpy array `x` of length `a`, but I want that if the user does not pass in anything, `x` is set to a random array of the same length. (If they pass in values of the wrong length, I can raise an error). Basically, I would like `x` to default to a random array of size `a`.

Here is my attempt at implementing this

```
import numpy as np 
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a
    def function(self, x = None):
        if x == None:
            x = np.random.rand(self.a)
        # do some more functiony stuff with x
```

This works if nothing is passed in, but if `x` is passed in I get `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()` i.e. it seems numpy doesn't like comparing arrays with `None`.

Defining the default value inline doesn't work because `self` is not in scope yet.

Is there a nice pythonic way to achieve this? To sum up I would like the parameter `x` to default to a random array of a specific, class-defined length.

Comment: The error is caused by doing a `==` test on an array.  Such a test produces a boolean array of the same size.  Does `if [True,False,True,False]:` make sense?  Fortunately in this case `is None` is the right alternative.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As a rule of thumb, comparisons of anything and `None` should be done with `is` and not `==`.

Changing `if x == None` to `if x is None` solves this issue.

```
class MyClass():
    def __init__(self, a):
        self.a = a

    def function(self, x=None, y=None):
        if x is None:
            x = np.random.rand(self.a)
        print(x)

MyClass(2).function(np.array([1, 2]))
MyClass(2).function()
#  [1 2]
#  [ 0.92032119  0.71054885]
```

Comment: This is actually one of the key reasons Python encourages `is None` instead of `== None`, and yet whenever people answer questions on “why are we supposed to use is None”, I forget—I mean those people forget—and instead focus on the original reasons and various less important things instead...